# Why are spaces between elements of chain so large?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I need to align a row of three buttons to the background view like this:

[image]

To do it I created a background view (`@drawable/background`) and a chain (`@id/button1`, `@id/button2`, `@id/button3`)

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**background.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="16dp" />
    <solid android:color="#11000000" />
</shape>
```

**button_background.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

However I get the following result:

[image]

I can't figure out, why the spaces between the views are so large. The chain is weighted as described in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html). There should be 4dp margins before the first view and after the last one and no spaces at all between the buttons.

**Update**

I've tried version 1.0.2 and all beta versions of constraint layout and I was able to reproduce the issue only in `constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta5`. Does it mean that there is a bug in this version of constraint-layout, or am I using it the wrong way?

**Update 2**

This is actually a bug in beta 5, and it is [fixed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74537416#comment2) in beta 6.

Comment: you code is working fine in my device

Comment: @MohammadAli It doesn't really matter, any will be ok.

Comment: Your code is running perfectly on my Pixel emulator. Try using a different device. Also make sure you are using correct min sdk version for constraint layou attribute in build.gradle.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using beta version of constraint layout, because I need barriers in my project. Can it be the issue?

Comment: @fdermishin may be because its working fine with `'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know *why* this is happening, and perhaps it is truly a bug in `1.1.0-beta5`, but...

The start/end margins you've applied to your `background` view are being inherited by the chain of three buttons because that chain is constrained to the start and end of the `background`. If you delete these margins, suddenly the "gaps" disappear:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[image]

Of course, you probably need those margins for your design. You can work around this issue by restoring the original margins to the `background` view and anchoring your chain to the parent instead of the background. That is, change the `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` attribute on `button1` to `"parent"`, and change the `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf` attribute on `button3` to `"parent"`:

[image]

The final piece of the puzzle is to change the start/end margins of the *chain* to mimic the old behavior. Previously you had the `background` view with `48dp` margins, and the chain with `4dp` margins. So, set the chain margins to `52dp` instead of `4dp` to include the background's 48dp:

[image]

My full XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button2"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, that workaround worked for me. However it is weird that margins of background affect margins of buttons. I've [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74537416) this to Google and I hope that they will change this behavior in the next version. For now I'm going to use beta4 version, as it works as expected.